# Checking if File.Exists() improves write speed

Tags: c#

My application writes some files to disc but I've realised I'm over writing existing files during this process. So, I need to check if the file exists first and then perform some logic.

There could be many files and as such, I wanted to gauge how much over head (in terms of time) the impact would be. So, I created a console application to test it.

My code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace TimeForFileRead
{
    class Program
    {
        static string myPath = "C:\\Users\\DRook\\Desktop\\temp\\";
        static string myPathFile = myPath + "file";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                DoSomeWork();
                Console.WriteLine(" =  =  =  =  =  =============== =  =  =  =  =");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void DoSomeWork()
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(myPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(myPath);    

            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

            stopWatch.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(myPathFile + i.ToString() + ".txt"))
                {
                    sw.Write(i.ToString());
                }
                i++;
            }

            stopWatch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("Write only: " + stopWatch.Elapsed);

            Directory.Delete(myPath, true);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(myPath);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

            stopWatch.Reset();

            stopWatch.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                if (!File.Exists(myPathFile + i.ToString() + ".txt"))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(myPathFile + i.ToString() + ".txt"))
                    {
                        sw.Write(i.ToString());
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Write and File check: " + stopWatch.Elapsed);
        }
    }
}
```

So, as you can see, it performs 2 actions. I is writing files to disk, the other is to check if the file already exists and if it doesn't, then write to disc.

A screen shot of my console window (the results):

[image]

As you can see, the strange thing is that it is nearly always quicker to first check if the file exists and then write it than it is to write direct to disc. This has left me confused. Surely this makes no sense. Why does this extra over head improve the speed (considering that the `File.Exists()` will always return false in my code so therefore the Write is not skipped)? I assume a fault in my code but I've looked at this for a while and I can't make sense of it.

**Edit**

As per the comments, I changed the order around a little, so I now perform the one with `File.Exists()` check first and then the write only. The results are more exaggerated (although I am now iterating over 10000 instead of 1000 as per the code above):

[image]

**Edit 2**

@MatthewWatson noted a fault with my code, I've updated it to ensure the directory is always deleted first. Same issue persists but at a greatly reduced occurrence yet a more dramatic difference in speed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace TimeForFileRead
{
    class Program
    {
        static string myPath = "C:\\Users\\DRook\\Desktop\\temp\\";
        static string myPathFile = myPath + "file";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                DoSomeWork();
                Console.WriteLine(" =  =  =  =  =  =============== =  =  =  =  =");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void DoSomeWork()
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(myPath))
                Directory.Delete(myPath, true);

            Directory.CreateDirectory(myPath);

            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

            stopWatch.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(myPathFile + i.ToString() + ".txt"))
                {
                    sw.Write(i.ToString());

                }
                i++;
            }

            stopWatch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("Write  took : " + stopWatch.Elapsed);

            Directory.Delete(myPath, true);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(myPath);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

            stopWatch.Reset();

            stopWatch.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                if (!File.Exists(myPathFile + i.ToString() + ".txt"))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(myPathFile + i.ToString() + ".txt"))
                    {
                        sw.Write(i.ToString());
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }

            stopWatch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("Write and check took: " + stopWatch.Elapsed);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The OS might cache the file when you make the exists-check.

Comment: `if (!Directory.Exists(""))` to `if (!Directory.Exists(myPath))`? Or even leave this line, it's not necessary. MSDN of Directory.CreateDirectory: If the directory already exists, this method does not create a new directory, but it returns a DirectoryInfo object for the existing directory.

Comment: @Andy, I agree it's not needed, that is not the question. The point is, it's an extra function (an extra overhead) yet, it speeds up the time it takes. Please note, File.Exist() will always return false.

Comment: Change the order of your tests. (perform the one with check prior, then write only). and see what happens.

Comment: Well the thing here is, those speed-ups aren't noticeable. It's only couple of percent in millisecond range. It might be a case when CLR can optimize the code during run or some caching, but still it's not really that significant.

Comment: This kind of test program is not going to tell you what is faster in the real world. Benchmarking is hard.

Comment: There are multiple things could be happening here, as @Wilbert suggested, definitely there could be caching going on, but not necessarily on FileExists check only. You are creating same directory and files and then deleting the directory and files, then recreating the same ones in same process. That could also be affecting the caching. Try for example the same test, but with Exists check first, then without it. Or, try a different directory/data file for each test..

Comment: @jnovacho - Fine, but if I increase the iterations from 1000 to 10000 then the difference is up to 1 second (where the File.Exists() route is up to 1 second faster).

Comment: @dognose, this has only proved my point more so (oddly) - see updated post.

Comment: In the first loop, you are overwriting files that already exist. In the second you are creating new files. This may cause the difference. To test this idea, change the code to also delete the directory before the first loop.

Comment: In addition to @MatthewWatson, add a `Thread.Sleep(5 sec)` after deleting the directories. Disk I/O can be async.

Comment: How many files will you write? ["We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize)

Comment: @RubensFarias, I am aware of this, my question isn't about if the additional time taken will cause a problem for my application now I know the extra time is minimal, it's about why is the result unexpected.

Comment: Considering how much work goes into optimising I/O in the OS, I doubt you'll ever even get to a conclusive list of confounding factors in your benchmark, much less a correct one.

Comment: @millimoose - thanks, that is good to know. If that makes the question unanswerable then fine as it's an unknown, then that is fine!

Comment: I've tried this on my system (adding delays of 5 seconds after deleting and recreating the directories) and I DO NOT see any significant differences in speed. In fact, sometimes the second loop is faster and sometimes the first loop is. Therefore I don't think this is actually a real thing (at least, not on my PC).

Answer (score 2):

Too much code to put in a comment - the short answer is that Exists + Write should generally take longer than just write (even for existing files).

Disk IO is not very predictable (caching, warm-up, machine load, IO queues, HDD/SSD model, etc) but running tests with a large number of iterations (more than 1000) that take more than a few ms should give you and idea. On my machine, Exists+Write generally take longer but there are exceptions too - it could be a page swap interfering or one of the VMs, who knows....

Here's a slightly modified test suite with 4 scenarios:
1. new folder, write only
2. new folder, exists + write
3. existing folder and files (from step 2) write only
4. existing folder and files (from step 2) exists + write

Code below:

```
class FTest
{
    static string myPath = "C:\\Users\\DRook\\Desktop\\temp\\";
    static string myPathFile = myPath + "file";

    public static void test()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            DoSomeWork();
            Console.WriteLine(" =  =  =  =  =  =============== =  =  =  =  =");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void testX1(string path, int index)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path + index.ToString() + ".txt"))
        {
            sw.Write(index.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static void testX2(string path, int index)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path + index.ToString() + ".txt"))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path + index.ToString() + ".txt"))
            {
                sw.Write(index.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path +"n"+ index.ToString() + ".txt"))
            {
                sw.Write(index.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    static void runTestMeasure(Action<string, int> func, int count, string message, bool cleanup)
    {
        if (cleanup)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(myPath)) Directory.Delete(myPath, true);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(myPath);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

        stopWatch.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            func(myPath,i);
        }

        stopWatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(message+": " + stopWatch.Elapsed);
    }

    static void DoSomeWork()
    {
        int count = 10000;
        runTestMeasure((path, ndx) => { testX1(path, ndx); },count,"Write missing file",true);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        runTestMeasure((path, ndx) => { testX2(path, ndx); }, count, "Write+Exists missing file",true);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        runTestMeasure((path, ndx) => { testX2(path, ndx); }, count, "Write existing file", false);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        runTestMeasure((path, ndx) => { testX2(path, ndx); }, count, "Write+Exists existing file", false);
    }
}
```

Check for yourself and see how it behaves on your machine. 
BTW: no point in having `i++;` inside for loops.

Edit: fixed `textX2` code to create new file (alternate name) if file exists

Answer (score 1):

Your tests have no warmup and you are putting the Exists outside of your timings. I guess that when you use the same file it can be cached somewhere on os or hardware level. To make this test better:

- Add warmup
- Use a random/unique filenames for each run
- Make your tests with 1000 and 10000 and 100000 files
- Make sure your gc is in the same state at the beginning of each test